# One of the Android Button work while the other does not

Tags: android, google-maps, button, android-activity

I did my best to solve the problem and I hope someone would be able to help me finding a solution.

I delcared the following layout for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context="com.example.youssef.mylocation.Main2Activity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:text="@string/menumessage"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="217dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/phone_number"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="@color/Color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/address"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/place_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@color/Color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Color"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Color"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CancelBtn"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:onClick="Cancelonbuttonclickfunc"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/city"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@color/Color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:text="Required !"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/AddBtn"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="464dp"
    android:text="Add"
    android:background="@color/Color"
    android:onClick="buttonClickFunction"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/CancelBtn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The related java code is the following:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView textView;
TextView laltitude;
TextView longitude;
Bundle bundle;
Double lal;
Double longt;


EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    laltitude =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    longitude =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    lal  = bundle.getDouble("laltitude");
    longt  = bundle.getDouble("longitude");
    laltitude.setText("laltitude : " + lal.toString());
    longitude.setText("longitude : " + longt.toString());

    //hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh        going back to main activity
//  CancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 //    public void onClick(View v) {
  //
   //     }
 //  });

    //hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
 //   AddButton.setOnClickListener({});
   // if (editText.getText() == null)
     //   textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   // else
   //     textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   // });

            }

public void buttonClickFunction(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),editText.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    if (editText.getText().toString() == "")
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void Cancelonbuttonclickfunc(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
}
}
```

The problem is that only one button seems to work (cancelbutton) but the 
but the add button does not seem work.

I did declare the button and use the `findViewById` method but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

In your button click method you're comparing strings using the `==` operator which tests for reference equality and not value equality. This is why your `textView`'s visibility never get set to VISIBLE. To check for value equality you should use `equals` method instead, like this:

```
public void buttonClickFunction(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),editText.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (editText.getText().toString().equals(""))
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Note that you also forgot to put `.show()` at the end of your Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final String text= edittext.getText().toString().trim();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (text.length() <= 0) {
                           textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```